# Position fixed y axis only inside scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to make a div which is inside another scrollable div fixed only y axis. I have tried a few things but the navbar keeps scrolling x axis aswell. I want it to be fixed only y axis and when scrolled x axis the nabar should scroll with it

Heres my code https://jsbin.com/qewopukuwo/2/edit?html,css,output

```
div.main { 
width:90%; 
height:400px;
overflow: scroll;
white-space: nowrap;
}

div.nav {
  position:fixed;
  background:red;
  padding:10px;
}

div.row {
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

div.content {
 display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  background:blue;
  color:white;
  padding:20px;
  text-align:center;
}

<div class="main">

<div class="nav">scrollable nav bar</div>  

  <div class="row">
<div class="content">1</div>
<div class="content">2</div>
<div class="content">3</div>
<div class="content">4</div>
<div class="content">5</div>
<div class="content">6</div>
<div class="content">7</div>
  </div>

   <div class="row">
<div class="content">1</div>
<div class="content">2</div>
<div class="content">3</div>
<div class="content">4</div>
<div class="content">5</div>
<div class="content">6</div>
<div class="content">7</div>
  </div>

 <div class="row">
<div class="content">1</div>
<div class="content">2</div>
<div class="content">3</div>
<div class="content">4</div>
<div class="content">5</div>
<div class="content">6</div>
<div class="content">7</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
<div class="content">1</div>
<div class="content">2</div>
<div class="content">3</div>
<div class="content">4</div>
<div class="content">5</div>
<div class="content">6</div>
<div class="content">7</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
<div class="content">1</div>
<div class="content">2</div>
<div class="content">3</div>
<div class="content">4</div>
<div class="content">5</div>
<div class="content">6</div>
<div class="content">7</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
<div class="content">1</div>
<div class="content">2</div>
<div class="content">3</div>
<div class="content">4</div>
<div class="content">5</div>
<div class="content">6</div>
<div class="content">7</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
<div class="content">1</div>
<div class="content">2</div>
<div class="content">3</div>
<div class="content">4</div>
<div class="content">5</div>
<div class="content">6</div>
<div class="content">7</div>
  </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

make the follwing changes to the div.main css

```
 height:100%;
 overflow-x: scroll;
```

This would make the Y axis stretch to full height of contents and scroll only x axis.

Comment: but the main needs to be 400px height

Comment: If you want to keep the height fixed, then you have to fit the data in that height. Your example at jsbin has data with collective height more than 400px. In that case your data will be trimmed.
You can use  `overflow-y: hidden;` to stop Y axis scroll. However this will trim the data beyond 400px.